# What is the deal with npm i and the package-lock file?

Tags: jenkins, npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

I believe I understand how `npm i` works, using the `package.json` file with the `dependencies` and versions of those libraries. I understand `package-lock.json` is the output of that build, with the specific versions down the tree. Future `npm i` will use the versions as specified in this lock file. Great!

My current issue is when we delete the `package-lock.json` file, `npm i` pulls down the **latest version** of the libraries, **ignoring** the version specified in `package.json`! Why would it do that?

We have a few libraries it was doing it on, but one that wreaked havoc in our new builds is: `"react-lazyload": "^2.6.2",`. When the lock file is deleted, it downloads `2.6.8` which introduces breaking changes to our UI. Why would `npm` grab the latest?

I checked the lock file and this is the only instance throughout the libraries using it, no other library is requesting a new version.

By the way, this only seems to happen on our Jenkins server, deploying all our code, which is running the same version of Node/npm as our dev machines:

```
node -v
v10.16.3
npm -v
6.9.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not ignore the version in the package.json it just follows semantic versioning rules.

If you use
`"react-lazyload": "^2.6.2"` this means that npm will download version 2.X.X of the package, getting the latest minor release (second number) and the latest patch (third number).

If you use `"react-lazyload": "~2.6.2"` it will download version 2.6.X of the package, getting only the latest patch (third number).

If you use `"react-lazyload": "2.6.2"` it will always download version 2.6.2

Comment: smh duh.... forgot about those decorators... thank you!